# Android ViewPager each tab one color

Tags: android, android-fragments

I use `ViewPager` to create 2 Fragments on an Activity like this:

```
public class ViewPagerAdapter extends FragmentStatePagerAdapter {
    int mNumOfTabs;

    public ViewPagerAdapter(FragmentManager fm, int NumOfTabs) {
        super(fm);
        this.mNumOfTabs = NumOfTabs;
    }

    @Override
    public Fragment getItem(int position) {

        switch (position) {
            case 0:
                Fragment1 tab1 = new Fragment1();
                return tab1;
            case 1:
                Fragment2 tab2 = new Fragment2();
                return tab2;
            default:
                return null;
        }
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return mNumOfTabs;
    }
}
```

I use it in an Activity like this:

```
<android.support.design.widget.TabLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="@dimen/tab_height"
    android:id="@+id/tab_layout"
    app:tabMode="fixed"
    app:tabGravity="fill"
    />

<android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:id="@+id/viewpager"
    android:layout_below="@id/tab_layout" />
```

This is the code in the Activity that holds the Fragments:

```
ViewPager view_pager;
ViewPagerAdapter adapter;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_acc1);

    TabLayout tab_layout = (TabLayout) findViewById(R.id.tab_layout);
    tab_layout.addTab(tab_layout.newTab().setText("Tab1"));
    tab_layout.addTab(tab_layout.newTab().setText("Tab2"));

    view_pager = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.viewpager);

    adapter = new ViewPagerAdapter
            (getSupportFragmentManager(), tab_layout.getTabCount());

    final ViewPager view_pager = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.viewpager);

    view_pager.setAdapter(adapter);

    view_pager.addOnPageChangeListener(new TabLayout.TabLayoutOnPageChangeListener(tab_layout));

    tab_layout.setOnTabSelectedListener(new TabLayout.OnTabSelectedListener() {

        @Override
        public void onTabSelected(TabLayout.Tab tab) {
            view_pager.setCurrentItem(tab.getPosition());
        }

        @Override
        public void onTabUnselected(TabLayout.Tab tab) {

        }

        @Override
        public void onTabReselected(TabLayout.Tab tab) {

        }
    });

}
```

Everything is ok, but I want the color of each tab like:
[image]

By that I mean that when you open each tab, it will change color.

**How do I do this ?**

update, follow LvN:
[image]

Comment: Implement _addOnPageChangeListener_ method for view pager.

Comment: @Piyush Gupta : in Activity hold Fragments?

Comment: @Piyush Gupta : i was update Activity code, can you fix it?

Answer (score 0):

Try with this :

```
    yourViewPager.addOnPageChangeListener(new ViewPager.OnPageChangeListener() {
        @Override
        public void onPageScrolled(int position, float positionOffset, int positionOffsetPixels) {
        }

        @Override
        public void onPageSelected(int position) {
             // set your colors here 
        }

        @Override
        public void onPageScrollStateChanged(int state) {

        }
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

**UPDATED**

You need to create custom tab views to achieve this.

*custom_tab.xml*

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
  <TextView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
  android:layout_width="wrap_content"
  android:layout_height="wrap_content"
  android:id="@+id/tab"
  android:textColor="@color/colorAccent"
  android:textSize="@dimen/tab_label"
  android:fontFamily="@string/font_fontFamily_medium"/>
```

And when you add items to tab, change the background color of the textview.

```
    TextView tabOne = (TextView) LayoutInflater.from(this).inflate(R.layout.custom_tab, null);
    tabOne.setText("TAB 1");
    tabOne.setBackgroundColor(Color.GREEN);        
    tabLayout.getTabAt(0).setCustomView(tabOne);

    TextView tabTwo = (TextView) LayoutInflater.from(this).inflate(R.layout.custom_tab, null);
    tabTwo.setText("TAB 2");
    tabTwo.setBackgroundColor(Color.YELLOW);        
    tabLayout.getTabAt(1).setCustomView(tabTwo);
```

Comment: Please add some explanation to your answer. Code-only answers are discouraged on SO. Thank you.

Comment: i got error in tabLayout.getTabAt(0).setCustomView(tabOne);

Comment: java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{noname.test1/noname.test1.Acc1}: java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException: Invalid index 0, size is 0

Comment: if i change "tabLayout.getTabAt(0).setCustomView(tabOne)" to "tablayout.addTab(tablayout.newTab().setCustomView(tabOne))", it is ok, but tab don't set full color, just a part of it. i was update image my question

Comment: You can customize that textview also you can set the padding for the tablayout...pp:tabPaddingStart="0dp"
    app:tabPaddingEnd="0dp"

Comment: i was try, on left and right is ok, but on top and bottom has white space.

Comment: use this tabPadding="0dp"

Comment: with that, it like image i post in my question.